# insert one block of data into database while other block is hidden

Tags: php

I have this code, and what it does is it inserts data to database. I have two  one is called autobox, second housebox. When I select auto from dropdown list the autobox tbody displays with a dropdown list and a text input. Samo with housebox. 
What I trying to accomplish is: When the autobox is displayed and housebox is hidden, and I fill up the form then submit it the housebox won't be inserted into database. 
I hope I clear about this

This code is not safe to use as it is: SQL INJECTION

```
  <script>
    function addSubject(){
   selectedSubject = document.getElementById('subcategory').value
   if (selectedSubject == 'auto'){
    document.getElementById('autobox').style.display = 'block';

}else if (selectedSubject == 'house'){
    document.getElementById('housebox').style.display = 'block';
   } 
   }
   </script>

   <?php    
   if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $description = $_POST['description'];
   $price = $_POST['price'];
   $subcategory = $_POST['subcategory'];
   $mileage = $_POST['mileage'];
   $make = $_POST['make'];


   $query = "INSERT INTO classifieds (id, subcategory, title, description, mileage, 

   make, price, broom ) VALUES ('', $subcategory, '$title', '$description', 

   '$mileage', '$make', '$price', '$broom')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

   } 
   ?>

   <form action="insert.php"  method="post" name="insert" enctype="multipart/form-

  data">

  <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" onchange="addSubject()"  >
   <option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>
  <option value="auto">Auto</option>
  <option value="house">House</option>
  </select>
  <span class="style64">Title</span> 
      <input type="text" name="title" class="input"/>

  <table>
  <tbody class="autobox"  id="autobox" style="display: none;" >
  <tr>
   <td class="title">Enter mileage:</td>
  <td class="field">
  <input type="text" name="mileage" size="8" maxlength="7"  /></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <span>Select Manufacturer : </span>

  <select name="make">
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody class="housebox"  id="housebox" style="display: none;" >
 <tr>
 <td class="title">Enter Price:</td>
 <td class="field">
  <input type="text" name="price" size="8" maxlength="7"  /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>

  <select name="broom">
<option value="1b">1 broom</option>
<option value="2b">2 broom</option>
<option value="3b">3 broom</option>
      </select>

   </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

   <textarea name="description" rows="5" class="input"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Continue" />
                    </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried naming your iput_posts uniquely. What I mean is if, 'auto', then your input_posts MAY have an indication that it belongs to the 'auto' table. After uniquely naming them, then you can  add a condition right before you will execute the query, if auto then execute query with unique 'auto' posts , else if house, execute query with unique 'house' posts.

Comment: question is not clear. i hope you want to insert autobox values when auto is selected in drop down box and housebox will be hidden and that values should not be inserted in to DB. If you are selecting housebox vice versa

Comment: Limi Jerin that's exactly what I want. CHi RiLo  I like your idea, but I don't know how to start it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least you need to get it working:

Only inserting the relevent fields:

```
 <?php    
 if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $subcategory = $_POST['subcategory'];

    if ($subcategory == 'auto'){
      $mileage = $_POST['mileage'];
      $make = $_POST['make'];
      $query = "INSERT INTO classifieds (subcategory, title, description, mileage, make, price) VALUES ($subcategory, '$title', '$description', '$mileage', '$make', '$price')";
    } elseif ($subcategory == 'house') {
      $broom = $_POST['broom'];
      $query = "INSERT INTO classifieds (subcategory, title, description, broom, price) 
                VALUES ($subcategory, '$title', '$description', '$price')";
    }

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 } 
 ?>
```

Hiding the non-active fields:

```
<script>
function addSubject(){
  selectedSubject = document.getElementById('subcategory').value;
  if (selectedSubject == 'auto'){
    document.getElementById('autobox').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('housebox').style.display = 'none';
  }else if (selectedSubject == 'house'){
    document.getElementById('housebox').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('autobox').style.display = 'none';
  } 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope this is what you want

**Code is not tested**

```
<script>
    function addSubject(){
   selectedSubject = document.getElementById('subcategory').value
   if (selectedSubject == 'auto'){
    document.getElementById('autobox').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('housebox').style.display = 'none';
}else if (selectedSubject == 'house'){
    document.getElementById('housebox').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('autobox').style.display = 'none';
   } 
   }
   </script>

   <?php    
   if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $description = $_POST['description'];
   $price = $_POST['price'];
   $subcategory = $_POST['subcategory'];
   $mileage = $_POST['mileage'];
   $make = $_POST['make'];
    if($subcategory=='auto')
    {
               $query = "INSERT INTO classifieds (id, subcategory, title, description, mileage, make, price, broom ) VALUES ('', $subcategory, '$title', '$description', 

       '$mileage', '$make', '', '')";
    }
    else
    {
       $query = "INSERT INTO classifieds (id, subcategory, title, description, mileage, make, price, broom ) VALUES ('', $subcategory, '$title', '$description', 

       '', '', '$price', '$broom')";
    }
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   } 
   ?>

   <form action="insert.php"  method="post" name="insert" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" onchange="addSubject()"  >
   <option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>
  <option value="auto">Auto</option>
  <option value="house">House</option>
  </select>
  <span class="style64">Title</span> 
      <input type="text" name="title" class="input"/>

  <table>
  <tbody class="autobox"  id="autobox" style="display: none;" >
  <tr>
   <td class="title">Enter mileage:</td>
  <td class="field">
  <input type="text" name="mileage" size="8" maxlength="7"  /></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <span>Select Manufacturer : </span>

  <select name="make">
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody class="housebox"  id="housebox" style="display: none;" >
 <tr>
 <td class="title">Enter Price:</td>
 <td class="field">
  <input type="text" name="price" size="8" maxlength="7"  /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>

  <select name="broom">
<option value="1b">1 broom</option>
<option value="2b">2 broom</option>
<option value="3b">3 broom</option>
      </select>

   </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

   <textarea name="description" rows="5" class="input"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Continue" />
                    </form>
```

if not this one let me know. thank you